# iOS7 - how to recognise when Safari toolbars are showing on mobile devices

Tags: css, safari, media-queries, ios7

Is it possible to recognise when the toolbars are showing in Safari iOS7 with a media query?

`(max-height: 215px)` is being ignored.

Thanks for any advice,
James

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely not a media query for it. The height the media query won't change with or without the toolbar. You may want to detect this with the *window.innerHeight* property with JavaScript.

Look at this (I have tested it on my iOS7 iPhone):

[Check out this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524216/detect-if-address-bar-is-shown-in-iphone-browser?answertab=active#tab-top)