# How do I prevent the URL-bar from messing with my layout on smartphone?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I've seen similar questions, but since there were only a few others who asked about this and I couldn't get my answer from them, I decided to ask about this myself.

**Description:**

I made a website with a simple layout. I gave an "initial-scale=1" to the viewport and it's made out of 5 divs, all styled with 100vh and 100vw.
When I view it on my phone and I scroll, the URL bar appears and resizes the area in which you see the content of the website, thus resizing the divs.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make the URL bar overlap the website, so that the content won't jump up and down after I scroll?
(preferably without jQuery)

Comment: I think this is your best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524216/detect-if-address-bar-is-shown-in-iphone-browser

Comment: Replacing 100vh by window.innerHeight might be the solution, but hiding the URL bar after a few seconds seems to me like it would only make the problem more obvious. The divs on my website adjust about a second after making the URL bar appear or disappear. Hiding the bar a few seconds later will just show that nasty adjustment again, without actually fixing the problem.

Comment: If the bar is not there, maybe you should introduce a spacing div, maybe with your logo or website name in place of it.

Comment: @gaynorvader A spacing div at the top would get pushed down by the URL bar as well, unless there is a way to make the URL bar overlap the website itself

Comment: If you detect when the URL bar is visible using the code in the link I posted, you can show/hide the spacer div depending on whether the URL bar is there.